# Regex to extract names from a string into a list

Tags: regex, vb.net, string

How is it possible to use regex just to extract the names from the following string:

```
Liam got 6,andy got 6
```

And add it to a list, i've tried using regex but i cant find the correct expression to extract just the names and am still a bit shaky on this area.

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Is the name always at the front of the clause (predictable structure), or is there a set list of names to pull from?

Comment: the name will always be in that same position, however the name may contain uppercase and lowercase characters

Comment: Will the remaining sentences will always be the same? I mean " got 6"

Comment: no the number will be between 0 and 10

Comment: That means, the pattern is always `[name] got [number]`?

Comment: Yeah it will always be that

Comment: @A.Kennedy OK, great! then you have non-regex solution! :) I think it is always good to have a non-regex solution first for simple case before we apply regex for performance benefit

Comment: @Ian there seems to be a problem, i applied your solution and when i use a for loop to display what is inside the array it only shows 1 name when it should display 4 :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105318/discussion-between-ian-and-a-kennedy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simple case, I always recommend not to use `Regex`, you could do it like this using `string.Split`, `string.Replace`, and `LINQ` `Where`:

```
Dim names As String() = sentence.Replace("got ", "").Split(" ").Where(Function(t) Char.IsLetter(t(0))).ToArray()
```

Suppose you have this `sentence`:

```
Dim separators As Char() = {",", " "}
Dim names As String() = sentence.Replace("got ", "").Split(separators, System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Where(Function(t) Char.IsLetter(t(0))).ToArray()
```

What happen step by step is:

```
"Andy got 6,may got 10, blue got 9, hERald got 0" 
"Andy 6,may 10, blue 9, hERald 0" 'After replace
"Andy" "6" "may" "10" "blue" "9" "hERald" "0" 'After split
"Andy" "may" "blue" "hERald" 'After where
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work in vb.net.

```
(?<=^|,)\w+
```

https://regex101.com/r/wT8rE9/1

And if it can have a space after the comma:

```
(?<=^|,|,\s)\w+
```

If you're comfortable with capture groups, you could do the following which should be more efficient:

```
(?:^|,\s*)(\w+)
```

Comment: it works but what if i wanted to include the comma in the regex, so it would extract like this: liam,andy,dylan,ben

Comment: If you want to go the regex route with substitution, this might give you an idea: https://regex101.com/r/eM6gL5/1.